# How to connect Aspera Connect with Aspera Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have configured Aspera On Cloud account. I have created a Aspera storage node for my s3 bucket. I am able to see the content of s3 bucket in files app. When I created the storage node it generated access & secret key.

To test aspera connect SDK, I downloaded the "all-in-one" example from below git repo and updated "remote_host", "remote_user" and "remote_password" with the my storage node endpoint and access key as remote_user and secret key as remote_password. Also, updated index.html  download function to point to files from my bucket.

https://github.com/IBM/aspera-connect-sdk-js/tree/main/examples/all-in-one

But when I open the index.html file in browser and try to download my Aspera connect plugin stucks at "Connecting" status and then eventually shows "Error: Failed to open TCP connection for SSH".

Please share your inputs on what could be the issue? Note: I am trying this from my home internet so there is no firewall that might be blocking. Also, I am able to download same file from Files app in Aspera on Cloud.

Thanks.